# Problemas realizando petición angular a una api rest

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, angular5

La api rest esta implementada con JWT , y debo setear en el header de la cabecera el token , lo hago como ven en el servicio pero cuando voy al navegador me da error 401, pero cuando modifico la peticion y le pongo el token de forma manual en el navegador , hace la petición bien , por lo cual puedo inferir que es que el servicio que muestro no esta seteando la cabecera , pero toda la documentacion que he consultado dice que es asi. Como podria hacer para que reconozca la cabecera.

Tengo este servicio en angular :

```
getUserMe(){
  console.log('Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('userToken'));
  return this.http.get(this.getMe, {headers : new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer 
'+localStorage.getItem('userToken')})}).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Saludos y muchas gracias

Comment: Si inspeccionas la petición en el navegador usando el devtools deberias ver si la cabecera está siendo seteada correctamente.

Comment: ya lo hice , y setea todo excepto el token , y no entiendo porque no lo hace porque se lo estoy seteando como he visto en la documentación